# linux printf to specified terminal line

Tags: linux, terminal

In **yocto**, when I use **bibake** to build one recipe, stages related with this recipe will be printed in multiple lines, very beautiful.
So I want implement a tiny example like it.

1. get current cursor's **row**
2. run 2 threads, one outputs something at **row + 1**, another outputs
   something at **row + 2**

As a result, I failed. Then I run 2 process which do same things, failed again.

Can some one give me some suggestions?
What I want is like:

```
ts:/home/test$ ./program1 &; ./program1 &

program1's output.....................
program2's output.....................
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '\n\n'

echo -ne "\033[6n"
read -rs -d\[ _
read -rs -dR foo
cursor_pos=$(cut -d";" -f1 <<< "$foo")
upper_row=$((cursor_pos - 2))
lower_row=$((cursor_pos - 1))

echo -ne  "\033[${upper_row};0H"
echo upper row
sleep 2
echo -ne  "\033[${lower_row};0H"
echo lower low
sleep 2
echo -ne  "\033[${upper_row};0H"
printf "\r\e[0K%s\n"  "upper again"
sleep 2
echo -ne  "\033[${lower_row};0H"
printf "\r\e[0K%s\n"  "lower again"
```

Comment: your solution does output one by one, not concurrent :( after I tried